# Basic cURL example to fetch html page contents from remote server

Tags: php, curl

Here is the code:

```
/*
* Example to fetch the example.com homepage into a file
*/

$curlObject = curl_init("http://AAA.BBB.CCC.DDD/");//AAA.BBB.CCC.DDD is the IP address of the remote server.

$file = fopen("example_homepage.txt", "w");

curl_setopt($curlObject, CURLOPT_FILE, $file);
curl_setopt($curlObject, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

curl_exec($curlObject);

curl_close($curlObject);

fclose($file);
```

It is based on the example [here](http://php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php). I am learning the basic cURL usage. The expected output is that the contents of the `index.php` or `index.html` located in the `htdocs` directory of the XAMPP server installed in my remote computer (whose IP is `AAA.BBB.CCC.DDD`) should be copied into the example_homepage.txt file once I execute this PHP script.

**Now the `example_homepage.txt` file IS created, but it is EMPTY.** Contents of the homepage (`index.php` or `index.html`) located in `htdocs` directory of the XAMPP server installed in remote machine are NOT copied in the newly created `example_homepage.txt`.

**The question is why and how do I fix this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The curl option CURLOPT_FILE never really worked for me, maybe buggy. Don't use it, there are other ways.
2. In order to receive the body content, set the option CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER with `curl_setopt($curlObject, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);` Otherwise you get nothing.
3. This worked perfectly for me (file_put_contents() creates the file if it doesn't exist).

   ```
   <?php
   $curlObject = curl_init("http://example.com/");
   curl_setopt($curlObject, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
   $result = curl_exec($curlObject);
   curl_close($curlObject);
   file_put_contents('example_homepage.txt', $result);
   ```

I tried it for google.de and this is the content of example_homepage.txt:

```
<HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<TITLE>301 Moved</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
<H1>301 Moved</H1>
The document has moved
<A HREF="http://www.google.de/">here</A>.
</BODY></HTML>
```

Use e.g. http://www.google.de/ and it will work as expected.